# In JDBC River how to stop housekeeping not to delete records?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

When JDBC River does the polling, housekeeping jobs removes chunk of records.

Somebody know solutions for it. I want to stop records deletion.

For more reference :- https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/issues/61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The housekeeping job is stop if versioning is disabled by `versioning: false` in the [JDBC river parameters](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/JDBC-River-parameters), which is the default.

```
{
    "jdbc" :{
    "strategy" : "oneshot",
    "driver" : null,
    "url" : null,
    "user" : null,
    "password" : null,
    "sql" : null,
    "sqlparams" : null,
    "poll" : "1h",
    "rounding" : null,
    "scale" : 0,
    "autocommit" : false,
    "fetchsize" : 10,
    "max_rows" : 0,
    "max_retries" : 3,
    "max_retries_wait" : "10s",
    "locale" : Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag(),
    "digesting" : true,
    "acksql" : null,
    "acksqlparams" : null          
    },
    "index" : {
    "index" : "jdbc",
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "bulk_size" : 100,
    "max_bulk_requests" : 30,
    "index_settings" : null,
    "type_mapping" : null,
    "versioning" : false,  
    "acknowledge" : false,
    }
}
```

`"versioning": true` if versioning should be used in the Elasticsearch indexed documents

By Reference :- https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/issues/133#issuecomment-30148180