# Lost results in ElasticSearch index with autoupdate

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have problem with data being lost when using a jdbc driver to update elasticsearch from a mysql database. My river is below:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/river_index_type/_meta' -d '
{
    "type": "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "strategy": "simple",
        "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost/tt",
        "user": "user",
        "password": "password",
        "sql": "SELECT p.product_id AS _id, ... FROM product p ... WHERE ...",
        "poll": "5m",
        "autocommit": true
    },
    "index": {
        "type": "type",
        "index": "index"
    }
}
```

Initially everything works fine, but later, instead of 1200 results in my index i only have 800-900, and each five minutes the count changes. I don't understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976566/in-jdbc-river-how-to-stop-housekeeping-not-to-delete-records) if problem of same as mine :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, one day I will unsubscribe)

Comment: That was better, but still lost data, five days everything worked fine, but now again lost about 200-300 records...