# Elasticsearch JDBC River Record Missing from Mysql when fetching in Bulk

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using `jdbc river` for elasticsearch to fetch bulk data from MySQL.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/company_river/_meta' -d '{
   "type": "jdbc",
   "jdbc": {
      "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
      "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname",
      "user": "username",
      "password": "password",
      "sql": "select id as _id, name, date, code, status from tablename",
      "strategy": "simple",
      "poll": "2s"
   },
   "index": {
      "index": "jdbc",
      "type": "jdbc",
      "versioning": true,
      "digesting": true,
      "bulk_size": 160,
      "max_bulk_requests": 5
   }
}'
```

The above command when I execute, It won't fetch all data from MySQL. Table contains more than 100M records.

Comment: Please have look similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976566/in-jdbc-river-how-to-stop-housekeeping-not-to-delete-records)